# How to get a PUT route to work correctly (and not return 404 error) with Axios and Express?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an app that makes this call:

```
handleUpdate (id, data) {
    const url = "/sites/" + id;
    axios.put(url, data)
        .then(res => {
            // handling of response
        })
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

The route in the server.js file is:

```
router.route('/sites/:site_id')
   .put(function(req, res) {
   // handling of update 
})
```

However, every time I make the handleUpdate call, I receive this message:

```
xhr.js:178 PUT http://localhost:3000/sites/5a39783d09ba9fec39b34d37 404 (Not Found)
```

The id is correct, but I'm clearly not doing something right.

Below is the applicable portion of the server.js:

```
//server.js
'use strict'

//first we import our dependencies...
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//and create our instances
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//set our port to either a predetermined port number if you have set 
it up, or 3001
var port = process.env.API_PORT || 3001;


//db config
var mongoDB =  // my mlab database connection info;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useMongoClient: true })
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

//now we should configure the API to use bodyParser and look for JSON 
data in the request body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//To prevent errors from Cross Origin Resource Sharing, we will set our 
headers to allow CORS with middleware like so:
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-
Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-
Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');

//and remove cacheing so we get the most recent comments
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
next();
});

//now  we can set the route path & initialize the API
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.json({ message: 'API Initialized!'});
});
```

Comment: try postman first, did you with that same ID?

Comment: can you show how you integrate the router in main server file?

Comment: With Postman, I still get this error: Cannot PUT /sites/5a39783d09ba9fec39b34d37

Comment: I've included now the server.js, Remario.

Comment: Do you even get a response if you place a `console.log` within the server route PUT handling...? If not, then you're going to have to give us more code from the **server.js** file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [method-override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) package in order to handle the put request:

1- install method-override package

```
npm install method-override --save
```

2- use it in your app

```
var express = require('express')
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
var app = express()

// override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'))
```

3- catch put request

```
router.route('/sites/:site_id').put(function(req, res) {
    // handling of update 
})
```

4- ajax

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'PUT'
    }
}

axios.post(url, data, config)
    .then(res => {
        // handling of response
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: YouneL, unforturnately, it's still not working. Do I need to do something to accommodate the site_id as a string? Does it need to be in ObjectId(site_id) format?

Comment: the id should be a string then you can cast it to objectID, `var oid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);`, I updated my answer please take a look

Comment: It's still not working unfortunately. I tried to incorporate an id-specific get route, and it's not working either.

Comment: router.route('/sites/:site_id')

  .get(function(req, res) {

    Site.find({_id: req.params.site_id}, function(err, site) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.json(site);
    })
  })

Comment: This results in a 404 as well. I seem to not be able to get to the id-specific route to work at all and cannot figure out why.

Comment: make sure that method-override middleware is before body-parser: `app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'))` then `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: you are using a get request change it to put: `router.route('/sites/:site_id') .put(function(req, res) { ... });`

Comment: Oh, no -- that's the get request that I tried to see if I could get router.route('/sites/:site_id') to work at all, and the get request throws a 404 too. I'm not sure why I can't get the route to work at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163007/discussion-between-younel-and-adam-white).

Answer (score 1):

I realized at long last that I was directing the PUT request to the main app and not to the api. Once I corrected for this, it worked perfectly.

How obvious errors seem once they've been solved.

Thanks to everyone who helped out.